# How to stop spam emails from a deleted account?

Tags: email, spam-prevention

My hotmail account was hacked a long time ago. I followed the steps recommended by Microsoft to change my password and then deleted my account. But the hacker**s** stole my contact list and is sending spam emails to my contact list (including friends, family, former teachers and professors) using my name but with a different email address.

I have already informed my contact list that I have been hacked but I want the hackers to stop sending any spam mails. Is that possible?

Comment: Paste the spam message received on [https://www.spamcop.net](https://www.spamcop.net) usually works pretty well.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have properly shut down the hotmail account.  I'm afraid that the simple answer is "No".
If you deleted it, you may have even allowed the spammer to legitimately create a new account under the same old address now too.

e-mail is not really authenticated - someone can send an email "from" any address to any other address as they please.  They can make one up or use a real one (or use their own).

The only way to prevent this is for each and every email relay on the internet to only relay mail to/from their own domains (ie close all "open relays").

For what it's worth, a spammer could have sent mail "from" your account without having had to hack it first.  The main thing they got from your account was your contact list and a brief time of being able to send e-mails that would have looked even more legitimate because hotmail would perceive them to be coming from "you - the person" as well as "you - the email address".

Comment: So any suggestions as to what I should do besides telling my contacts that I have been hacked?

Comment: Consider recreating the email account - there's no need to delete it and make it available to others.
If spammers are sending mail that appears to come from you, but via the wrong mail relay (hotmail won't be letting them), your contacts' email clients should actually detect this, especially if they manually mark a few as spam.

You probably should tell them about the hack though too, yeah.